# Flexigrid- How to bind data to flexigrid(jquery)?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I am trying to use flexigrid(jquery) to display my data.. I have downloaded some examples but somehow i have not been able to figured out "How to bind the data to flexigrid" which i am fetching using ajax, and which currently is in array.. Basically i dont know how tryconvert my data in Json object.. Or is their any other way(I dont want to use php file to return my data).. and also please refer some useful links which i can follow to learn flexigrid in detail right from basics.. Most of the sites which i refered dont go in much details about flexigrid... I know, this 1 is very stupid, but I cant help as I have just beginned using flexigrid...

Answer (score 1):

I think this explains everything pretty well. [Flexgrid asp.net mvc](http://rommelmanalo.blogspot.com/2008/10/flexgrid-aspnet-mvc-and-jquery.html)

Comment: Even i have a similar Question. I referred your answer but I can't use MVC as i want my application to be deployed on web!!! Please help me out!!!